# Conflict between amsthm, cref, and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, amsthm

I cannot determine why this does not compile unless I remove `amsthm` which I normally include, though I don't exactly know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools, thmtools}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}


\declaretheorem[style=plain,numberwithin=section,name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,sibling=theorem,name=Lemma]{lemma}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a test.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
This is a test.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `cleveref` package is one of the few packages which should be loaded after `hyperref`

Comment: The *first* error I get when I compile your code is "`cleveref` must be loaded after `hyperref`!". After doing that, the code compiles. Do you read your `.log`?